# Install RV 30A outlet to code

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, receptacle

I'm planning to DIY install an TT-30R outlet ([Amazon item B000BQMX3K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BQMX3K)) using an existing construction box [(Amazon item B00H8NUVRO)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H8NUVRO) within a few feet of a main subpanel with 10/2 wire and a [30A 120V breaker (HOM130CP)](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-30-Amp-Single-Pole-Circuit-Breaker-HOM130CP-HOM130CP/202353319), and I've been looking online for guides to ensure I do everything to code, but have not found anything great thus far which goes into that aspect.  I'm not thinking there's much to it - is there anything beyond the below or details that I may not have in mind?

1. Turn off mains to the panel
2. Add breaker to empty slot
3. Remove drywall and screw in box
4. Run wire between box and panel
5. Secure wire before point of entry to stud using a staple
6. Connect the wires appropriately to the breaker and to the outlet contacts
7. Install face plate and close up and turn mains back on

Comment: Will you be providing GFCI protection to this receptacle?  Is this for a generator, RV or tiny house?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica it's for an RV. Should that have its own GFCI built in as needed for its outlets or do I need to add something?  My concern with installing a GFCI breaker was that it'd trip from the RV AC or fans, but then looked it up and thought maybe the breakers in the RV would provide the protection anyways. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

30A 1-pole breakers have no useful use except RV outlets.  I for one prefer to use a 30A 2-pole here, as it can be reused for other things. Just ignore the other hot terminal, unless you have a second RV spot.

In NEC 2020 states (which have not made an exemption), you will need GFCI protection for the outlet.

- 30A GFCI receptacles do not exist (except for EVSEs, which are no help here).
- 30A deadfronts, I cannot find any.
- 30A *single pole* GFCI breakers are a black swan. Good luck finding one at a sane price.
- 30A *double pole* GFCI breakers are readily available and I think that is the way to go.

I cannot advise whether a HOMeline breaker is correct because you didn't say if you have a HOMeline panel.  Breakers are *not* interchangeable across brands. They will seem to fit, but won't engage the bus stab properly and will burn up the connection.

Feel free to put the wire(s) on the breaker before you put the breaker in the space.

All breaker and socket connections should be torqued to spec. NEC 110.14.

If you are fishing the cable into place, they waive the requirement to staple the cable to the stud. This is to improve your ability to getting it done without any drywall work.  Cut the hole carefully is all.